# Can Halo 3 ODST’s Firefight Mode be played on LAN? (Xbox 360)

Tags: xbox-360, halo-3-odst

How many players, and in what split screen configurations, can ODST Firefight be played on LAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two sources that I found seem to indicate that you can have a maximum of 2 players play Firefight in split screen on one console:

- [Source One](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/954261-halo-3-odst/51092678)
- [Source Two](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/xbox360/954261-halo-3-odst/answers/111598-does-this-game-have-4-player-split-screen-in-firefight-mode)

According to the second source, it states:

> No it does not have 4-player split screen for firefight. it does have 2 player split screen, 4 player online co-op, and you CAN use your 2 player split screen and pick up 1-2 others online for a 3-4 player match.

[The wiki](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Firefight) for Firefight says you can use [System Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Link) to enable 4 player local play with split screen (2 people on each system).  So if you are looking to play with the 4 character maximum locally, this is probably the option you are looking for.